# jQuery searchable dropdown plugin bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

Firstly I would like to say, that i am fairly new to jQuery and javascript. I am trying to use plugin called *jQuery searchable dropdown plugin* ([it's source code](http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/jquery.searchabledropdown.js)). Also I have tried Select2 and Chosen and I don't like them, hard to customize and buggy.

On my page, users can append new select inputs (must have feature) and that causes some visual problems with this plugin.

I created a simple demonstration (jsfiddle.Net/sf42v/), click "Add new input" several times and You can see that first select input is getting bigger and bigger.

Firstly thank You for reading this post and I would really appreciate if You could say how to solve this problem.

Demo code for posterity:

#### html

```html
<button type='button' id='addItem'>Add new input</button>
<form id='inputs'>
    <div>
        <select class='selectSearch'>
            <option>Test1</option>
            <option>Test2</option>
            <option>Test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### js

```js
$('.selectSearch').searchable();

var container = $('#inputs');

$('#addItem').on('click', function () {
    $("<div><select class='selectSearch'><option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option><option>Test3</option></select></div>").appendTo(container);
    $('.selectSearch').searchable();
    lenght++;
});
```

Comment: I was also trying to debug this plugin and found this one instead: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the plugin on *all* the selects each time you add one.

You could do something like this instead;

```
var container = $('#inputs');
$('#addItem').on('click', function () {
    var newSelect = $("<div><select class='selectSearch'><option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option><option>Test3</option></select></div>");
    newSelect.appendTo(container);
    newSelect.find(".selectSearch").searchable(); // only apply to the new select
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sf42V/1/

Comment: I have also another problem, IE10 doesn't display text in searchable select input, when I am starting to typing.

Comment: @user2650096 What version of jQuery are you using? IE10 seems to have issues (at least in jsfiddle) if I choose anything higher than 1.8.3

Comment: I use jQuery 2.0.3 and jQuery Migrate 1.2.1 (jQuery searchable dropdown plugin wouldn't work without it)

Comment: I found another bug, if I append another select and try to change the last one value, select opens behind the next one.

Comment: @user2650096 I don't think this is related to your original question. If you post a new question along with some more details (screenshots and relevant code and a description) it will be easier to help you.